# Android studio 2.3.1: Gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I started a new project in android studio 2.3.1. It started showing the following errors.

```html
E:\My_Fun_Projects\Android\MyAndroidApps\MyApplication1\app\build.gradle
    Error:Error:line (38)Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
<a href="openFile:E:/My_Fun_Projects/Android/MyAndroidApps/MyApplication1/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1
<a href="openFile:E:/My_Fun_Projects/Android/MyAndroidApps/MyApplication1/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
<a href="openFile:E:/My_Fun_Projects/Android/MyAndroidApps/MyApplication1/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
<a href="openFile:E:/My_Fun_Projects/Android/MyAndroidApps/MyApplication1/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
<a href="openFile:E:/My_Fun_Projects/Android/MyAndroidApps/MyApplication1/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
<a href="openFile:E:/My_Fun_Projects/Android/MyAndroidApps/MyApplication1/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
<a href="openFile:E:/My_Fun_Projects/Android/MyAndroidApps/MyApplication1/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `testCompile 'junit:junit:x.xx'` from `build.gradle` file, it should work fine.

If you want junit, then you may need to add the repository url. Because android studio might not have the junit library.

```
android{
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are connected to internet.

If you live in a country like Iran you should use VPN and resync your project.

Answer (score 0):

it worked by removing the`testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`  on the app level gradle file in the dependencies area (down at the bottom of the page)